# Unable to overide the wsdl location in apache cxf 2.4.6

Tags: java, apache, web-services, wsdl, cxf

i have placed the wsdl files in

```
E:/testworkspace/projectname/docroot 
                  WEB-INF
                       src
                         com
                           test
                             wsdl
```

if i give the full path say wsdlLocation =  "`file:E:/testworkspace/projectname/docroot/WEB- INF/src/com/test/wsdl/some.wsdl`" , it picks the WSDL file.

but i need to make generic something like directly fetching:

```
        @WebServiceClient(name = "TestInterfaceService", 
        wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/some.wsdl",                  
        targetNamespace = "http://www.google.com/job") 

     public class TestInterfaceService extends Service {
     public final static URL WSDL_LOCATION;
     public final static QName SERVICE = new QName("http://www.google.com/job", "TestInterfaceService");
     public final static QName TestInterfaceSoapHttpPort = new QName("http://www.google.com/job", "TestInterfaceSoapHttpPort");
  static {
    URL url = null;
    try {

        url = new URL("WEB-INF/wsdl/some.wsdl");

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TestInterfaceService.class.getName())
            .log(java.util.logging.Level.INFO, 
                 "Can not initialize the default wsdl from {0}", "WEB-INF/wsdl/some.wsdl");
    }
    WSDL_LOCATION = url;
}
```

Can you please suggest how to pick WSDL files independently from that of my local system, currently it throws the error Can not initialize the default wsdl from `WEB-INF/wsdl/some.wsdl`

Comment: Is the project you are building a maven based?

Comment: No its not on maven based

Comment: Is this a dynamic web project?

Answer (score 0):

You need a valid URL string to be able to create a new URL. If your service does expose the URL, it might be an option to use that.

If your client is a web application, another option is to make the wsdl available via your application and reference it from there using http://localhost/app/some.wsdl

Hope that helps

Comment: How do i add that In  wsdlLocation here   @WebServiceClient(name = "TestInterfaceService", 
        wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/some.wsdl",                  
        targetNamespace = "http://www.google.com/job") ? the above solution wont work for this wsdlLocation  :(

Comment: wsdlLocation must be a URL see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/ws/WebServiceClient.html#wsdlLocation(). Use the published wsdl to your webservice. Or make your wsdl available via http in your client

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achive here, the configuration: `wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/some.wsdl"` is perfectly fine as long as WSLD file is under `WEB-INF/wsdl`, if you placed the wsdl in `WEB-INF/src/com/test/wsdl` and specifying WSDL location like this: `wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/some.wsdl` - of course it won't work, add your WSDL in `WEB-INF/wsdl` and all will be fine.

Comment: yes i had placed the WSDL file in WEB-INF/wsdl/Some.wsdl, yet it says Can not initialize the default wsdl from WEB-INF/wsdl/some.wsdl.